# Rails has_many with source and conditions doesn't create condition attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to setup a `has_many` with `conditions` which works fine for the reading part but not for new entries. I've tested it some weeks ago in a sandbox and it worked but I can't get it work again so maybe I'm just blind or it is just a wrong design :-)

```rails
class Task
  has_many :task_users
  has_many :assignees, :through => :task_users, :source => :user, :conditions => {"task_users.is_assignee" => true}
  has_many :participants, :through => :task_users, :source => :user
end

class TaskUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end

class User
  has_many :tasks
end
```

After adding a new assignee to a task like this

```rails
Task.first.assignees << User.first
```

the following SQL is executed

```sql
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `task_users` (`created_at`, `is_assignee`, `task_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-11-18 15:52:24', NULL, 2, '2012-11-18 15:52:24', 3)
```

I thought rails will use my conditions to set these values when I'm add ing new ones. Reading works great but I have no idea why adding new values doesn't work with conditions.

I expect this INSERT

```sql
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `task_users` (`created_at`, `is_assignee`, `task_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-11-18 15:52:24', 1, 2, '2012-11-18 15:52:24', 3)
```

Comment: Is your join table called `task_users` or `item_users`? It looks like you're using these interchangeably. Could you clarify?

Comment: it is called `task_users` just misstyped `task` with `items` sometimes :( 

Fixed typos in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether you can specify `:conditions` hash on the join table in a `has_many :through` association. Someone else correct me if I'm wrong, but the condition has to be directly on the source association, `:user` in your case.

If this is the case, to work around this you can specify an auxiliary association:

```
has_many :task_users
has_many :assignee_task_users, :class_name => 'TaskUser', :conditions => {"is_assignee" => true}
has_many :assignees, :through => :assignee_task_users, :source => :user
```

Comment: Wow this is it. First test worked but need to dig deeper a bit later this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

just going to highlight the documentation:

```
Specify the conditions that the associated objects must meet in order to be 
included as a WHERE SQL fragment, such as price > 5 AND name LIKE 'B%'. 
Record creations from the association are scoped if a hash is used. 
has_many :posts, :conditions => {:published => true} will create published 
posts with @blog.posts.create or @blog.posts.build.
```

even though you used an hash already, the first parameter is a string, which is unneded to be (the association knows already the table name). rewrite it as :conditions => {:is_assignee => true} and it should work.

Also, the way you are creating users should be rewritten in order for this to work of course. Instead of:

```
Task.first.assignees << User.first
```

use:

```
Task.first.assignees.create
```

and that should do the trick.

Comment: I tried `:conditions => {:is_assignee => true}` yesterday and I need the join table name because I am using a `source`.

I tried .create as well, but can't get it work.